# Why should I “enclose the previous parenthesis with ‘{}’”?

Tags: brackets, superscripts, alignment

I stumbled across this line in chktex ([here](https://github.com/sharelatex/chktex/blob/master/ChkTeX.tex.in#L906)) with a note saying

> This is a warning which you may ignore, but for maximum aestethic
>   pleasure, you should enclose your bracket characters with `{}'s.

What happens (technically) if I add these brackets?

The following MWE shows the difference with and without the additional brackets; note that the version *with* the additional brackets results in the superscript being a little bit higher (which, according to chktex seems to be preferred?).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\title{}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\{X\}^T
{\{X\}}^T
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's simply wrong advice. Complain with the developers of `chktex`. If you want to avoid the wrong warning, use `\lbrace X\rbrace^T`.

Comment: So the slightly higher superscript is not desired?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apparently, the developer of `chktex` advises to always do something like

```
{(a+b)}^2
```

which is ***not*** what's normally done. There's no need for it and the output is very disputable in typographic terms: compare by yourself, left the normal, right the braced combo:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
(a+b)^2 \quad {(a+b)}^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
(\sqrt{2}+1)^2 \quad {(\sqrt{2}+1)}^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second one is obviously wrong. The warnings of `chktex` are

```latex
Warning 3 in badchk.tex line 5: You should enclose the previous parenthesis with `{}'.
(a+b)^2 \quad {(a+b)}^2
    ^
Warning 3 in badchk.tex line 9: You should enclose the previous parenthesis with `{}'.
(\sqrt{2}+1)^2 \quad {(\sqrt{2}+1)}^2
           ^
```

and I heartily disagree.

Comment: On one hand it is uglier with the dynamically scaling exponent height, but on the other hand semantically in tex `(a+b)^2` means that the right parenthesis has a superscript, rather than the whole expression, which makes me feel unclean.

Comment: @SamYonnou Don't feel unclean. That's how it has been done for a few centuries. The exponent is indeed to the whole expression delimited by the parenthesis: no need to add levels.

Comment: I mean in tex as a computer language specifically, not in conventional mathematical notation

Comment: @SamYonnou Really, that's the way it should be done. Braces around math material make a subformula, where spaces are frozen and other things happen. Sometimes it's useful, generally it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Using braces seems to be either **irrelevant** or **bad**.

**In display mode**,

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left(\sqrt 2 + 1\right)^2 = {\left(\sqrt 2 +1\right)}^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

the result is identical.

**Inline**, using braces disturbs the interline spacing.

**No braces** `(\sqrt 2 + 1)^2`:

[image]

**Braces** `{(\sqrt 2 + 1)}^2`:

[image]

**Conclusion**: disable chktex Warning 3 permanently.